# missing parameter type for expanded function for primitive to char conversion

Tags: scala, types, parameters

I know that there are similar question floating on stack-overflow.

But, it will be great, if any simple explanation for below is available some where.

```
val arr1 = Array.tabulate(5)( (_+65) )
```

compiles fine.

```
val arr2 = Array.tabulate(5)( (_+65).toChar )
```

is a compile time error.

Also, i am wondering how to use **-Ytyper-debug** as described by **@som-snytt** in
[Scala: missing parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357353/scala-missing-parameter-type?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when compiler compile:

```
Array.tabulate(5)( (_+65) )
```

it will equal to:

```
Array.tabulate(5)(x => (x + 65 ) )
```

but for:

```
Array.tabulate(5)( (_+65).toChar )
```

it will be expanded to an anonymous function:

```
Array.tabulate(5)( (x => x + 65).toChar )
```

the compiler will lose the context of `x` in function body.

You can use `scala -Ytyper-debug` to see the details:

the type debug outputs:

```
((x$1) => x$1.$plus(65)).toChar
```

Comment: @checgpohi : Is there any shortcut to use toChar other then val arr = Array.tabulate( 5 )( ( i: Int ) => { ( i + 65 ).toChar } )

Comment: You can define a function `def f(x: Int)  = (x + 65).toChar` and use `Array.tabulate(5).map(f(_))` to calculate

Comment: a bit ugly, but possible: `Array.tabulate[Char](5)(_.+(65).toChar)`

Comment: un, why don't you like this `Array.tabulate(5)(x => (x + 65 ).toChar)`? it's cleaner and more readable.