# Scala: .to[Seq] vs .toSeq on collections

Tags: scala

What's the difference between `someCollection.to[Seq]` and `someCollection.toSeq`? One thing I noticed is that when called on a `Map`, `.toSeq` generally returns a `Vector`, while `.to[Seq]` usually returns an `ArrayBuffer`, but I'm not sure what it really means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `to[T]` method of Scala's collection is the more generic function. It requires as an implicit parameter a value of type `CanBuildFrom[From, Elem, To]` which defines how one can construct a collection `To` with elements of type `Elem` from `From`. Usually, the `toSeq`, `toList`, `toMap`, ... directly forward to this method, as it is the case for `Set`, for example.

However, some classes offer a special implementation for certain `toXXX` methods in order to be more efficient. This is the case for the `toSeq` implementation of the `Map` class which internally calls `toBuffer`. `toBuffer` returns an `ArrayBuffer`. In contrast to that, the more generic `to[Seq]` method will be called with a `CanBuildFrom` implicit value which returns a `Vector` collection which is immutable.

Comment: So can I assume that if there are no special reasons, I should lean towards the `toXXX` methods instead of `to[XXX]`?

Comment: Examples where it matters. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28163729/1296806 or `(1 to 10).to[Set](3)`